# Lucene++ error on installation Poedit 1.8.12 on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, poedit

Such as the title says, I am having an error on the installation of Poedit 1.8.12 on CentOS 7.

I have installed Lucene++ (almost every version from GitHub) but I always get the same error message:

```
checking for pkg-config... /bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for wx-config... /usr/local/bin/wx-config
checking for wxWidgets version >= 3.0.1 (--unicode)... yes (version 3.0.2)
checking for wxWidgets static library... no
checking if wxWidgets includes XRC... yes
checking for wxrc... /usr/local/bin/wxrc-3.0
checking for mkdtemp... yes
checking for ICU... yes
checking if wxWidgets toolkit uses GTK+ 3... yes
checking for GTKSPELL... yes
checking for LUCENE... no
configure: error: missing Lucene++ library
[root@localhost poedit-1.8.12]#
```

I was wondering if I have to install something like lucene++-devel, but I have not found the way to do this so far.

My CentOS 7 is 64 bits, and is a virtual machine mounted with VMWare.

Has anyone had the same problem? How did you solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I tried to instal Poedit.

The `configure` of Poedit uses `pkg-config` to find the libs, but the Lucene++ installer don't copy the `liblucene++.pc` file to the directory of `pkg-config`.

The solution is just copy the file in `{Lucene++Root}/build/lucene++.pc` to one of the directories of `pkg-config` (you can see it on `man pkg-config`).